# How to do sorting when writing the dataframe to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to sort based on date column or any other when writing dataframe to an excel file.?

```
df_sales.to_excel(writer, sort='Date',sheet_name='Summary')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, necessary before by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df_sales.sort_values('Date').to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary')
```

Test for pandas 0.25 for sorting by python dates:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=5)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': [1,5,3,9,2]})  
df = df.sort_values('a')

print (df)
        Date  a
0 2017-04-03  1
4 2017-04-07  2
2 2017-04-05  3
1 2017-04-04  5
3 2017-04-06  9

df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date

print (df.sort_values('Date'))
         Date  a
0  2017-04-03  1
1  2017-04-04  5
2  2017-04-05  3
3  2017-04-06  9
4  2017-04-07  2
```

Comment: How to sort if date is in object datatype?